# What's the purpose of 'Roaming' folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there directories called Local, LocalLow, and Roaming under \Users\<username>?](https://superuser.com/questions/21458/why-are-there-directories-called-local-locallow-and-roaming-under-users-usern)

What's the purpose of the following folder in windows?

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming`

So far I've found is that, every app I install, a folder with its name is created in this folder. But, what's the purpose?

Comment: as well as: [What is the difference between “local” and “roaming” folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/150012/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-roaming-folders)

Comment: Good catch @slhck. :)