# What is the difference between “Local” and “LocalLow” folders?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there directories called Local, LocalLow, and Roaming under \Users\<username>?](https://superuser.com/questions/21458/why-are-there-directories-called-local-locallow-and-roaming-under-users-user)

I know what Local and Roaming are for.  But what's the difference between Local and LocalLow?   I LocalLow really another form of Roaming, but uses only a small bandwidth to slowly update files across the domain for the user?

Comment: More like **exact** duplicate.

Comment: It may be an exact duplicate, but it is not answered well yet at the other question.