# What in windows folder AppData?

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there directories called Local, LocalLow, and Roaming under \Users\<username>?](https://superuser.com/questions/21458/why-are-there-directories-called-local-locallow-and-roaming-under-users-user)

What is folder `C:\Users\abc\AppData` used for in Windows and particularly Windows 7? I have lot of old data in  `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming`, is it safe to delete it?

Is this data useful, if not why is not cleaned up by the system itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppData` folder contains those portions of your user-specific system and program configuration data that are not stored in the registry. So, no, it most certainly is **NOT** safe to delete the folder. Leave it alone unless you know what you're doing.