# My Users folder is over 17GB but has almost nothing in it

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have an SSD boot drive with Windows 7 on it. I keep all (most) of my applications on my HDD. I keep getting a message telling me my C: drive is almost full. I go to find the problem and see my Users folder has over 17GB in it (or so `Properties` of the folder tells me) and I then check the `Properties` of all its subfolders and none are even close to 1GB! What could be my problem here? How can I find the culprit?

Comment: have you checked the hidden folders ?

Comment: check my comment to the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Tools` -> `Folder Options` -> then `View` tab.

Make sure your settings match this picture:

[image]

Comment: I did and I found the AppData folder is huge. What can I do to it?

Comment: The AppData folder is where much of the configuration settings of your programs are stored. Also lots of temporary files are stored there as well. [Check out this question as well as other questions related to it:](http://superuser.com/questions/21458/why-are-there-directories-called-local-locallow-and-roaming-under-users-user)

Comment: I found Apple Computer has 10GB in it. Can I just copy that over to another drive safely?

Comment: I'd advise against modifying the folder structure in any way. [However, look into creating symbolic links.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Comment: I decided to just move the folder. There is nothing in there I use since I got rid of my iPhone a while back. Plus, I am planning on doing a clean Windows install in the next few months on a couple of new drives I plan to get. I have over 10GB free now on my SSD. I am happy.

Answer (score 1):

While Chris Tarazi seems to have answered the question above, note that you can use the free application [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) (Windows Directory Statistics) to get a very detailed view of your SSD or HDD layout. It shows all your files in a hierarchical graphical view.  If you're wondering what the biggest files are in your file system, it will easily show you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been using iTunes for backing up iPhones, then it would take a huge amount of size on

> C:\Users[your pc name]\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\backup

because it will have all previous backups from all phones.